# Button Flyout has a border I can't remove

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have a button with a flyout and for some reason I can't remove the border, white, around the black grid. Any suggestions?

**Picture of output**

[image]

**Xaml Implementation**

```
<Button Foreground="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="30" Height="30" Margin="0,0,15,5">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/ButtonImage.png" />
        </Button.Background>
        <Button.Flyout>
            <Flyout  Placement="Top"    >
                <Grid Width="300" Height="auto" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="Black"  BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="blue" >

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid Height="50" Grid.Row="0" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Black">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="SSMenuAppVersionText" Text="123" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                    <Grid x:Name="AppSuggestionGrid" Grid.Row="1" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Black">
                            <Button x:Name="AppSuggestionButton" Click="FeedBackButtonClicked" Background="Transparent" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="SSMenuAppSuggesstionText" Text="App Suggestions" Foreground="#007AFF" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Black">
                        <Button x:Name="ReferButton" Click="ReferButtonClicked" Background="Black" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="SSMenuReferText" Text="Refer " Foreground="#007AFF" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="3" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Black">
                        <Button x:Name="VisitButton" Click="VisitButtonClicked" Background="Black" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="SSMenuVisitText" Text="Visit " Foreground="#007AFF" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>

                </Grid>
            </Flyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have options. If we go look at the guts of the [Flyout Style Template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299125.aspx) we notice some set theme resources for `Padding` and `Border` which you can use to either override the properties, or just create your own `Style` template for `Flyout` and make them whatever you like.

So for example if you went and tossed something like this into your resource dictionary, you should override the `ThemeResource` for the app.

```
<Thickness x:Key="FlyoutContentThemePadding">0,0,0,0</Thickness>
<Thickness x:Key="FlyoutBorderThemeThickness">0</Thickness>
```

Hope this helps, cheers!